# Python: stimulus change at a random time

Tags: python

I am trying to make a task in which the fixation cross will change of color (from white to red) at a random time (in seconds) around 60 seconds. So, at 5s, 10s, 45s or 55s. I tried an if else loop, but I get an error: fixation.draw()
NameError: name 'fixation' is not defined for the last fixation.draw() in the script, and I don't get why. I tried to define the fixation before the loop but it didn't work, also I think I defined it in the if else loop, but maybe I am wrong. Here is the code:

```
from psychopy import visual, event, core, data, gui
from psychopy.hardware.emulator import launchScan
import time
from numpy.random import random, randint, normal, shuffle

globalClock = core.Clock()


class MyStim(object):
    def __init__(fixation):
        fixation()

        fixationtimes = list(range(60))
        win = visual.Window([1280, 800], monitor="testMonitor",fullscr=True)

        if fixationtimes == [5, 10, 45, 55]: # create list
            shuffle(fixationtimes) # randomize order
            fixation = visual.GratingStim(win=win, units="deg", size=2, pos=[0, 0], sf=0, color="red", autoDraw=True)
        else:
            fixation = visual.GratingStim(win=win, units="deg", size=2, pos=[0, 0], sf=0, color="white", autoDraw=True)

    fixation.draw()
    win.flip()
    core.wait(2.0)

myStim = MyStim()

win.flip()

core.quit()
```

The code is probably very inefficient, because I am new to Python. If anyone can help, please :)!

Answer (score 0):

Your error happened because **init**() function actually doesn't happen immediately.
This code is a simple demonstration.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("hi from init!")

    print("hi!")

myClass = Foo()
```

This outputs

```
hi! hi from init!
>>>
```

So, **init**() function is called only after every line inside the class is executed.

Also, when you are defining a class, writing your codes outside of the methods is usually not advisable. Create a function if you want the class to do something :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured I could do it without the class function. So I made the following:

```
globalClock = core.Clock()
win = visual.Window([1280, 800], monitor="testMonitor",fullscr=True)
fixationtimes = list(range(60))

for i in fixationtimes:
    if  (i == 5 or i == 10 or i == 45 or i == 55): # create list
        fixation = visual.GratingStim(win=win, units="deg", size=2, pos=[0, 0], sf=0, color="red", autoDraw=True)
        fixation.draw()
        win.flip()
        core.wait(1.0)
    else:
        fixation = visual.GratingStim(win=win, units="deg", size=2, pos=[0, 0], sf=0, color="white", autoDraw=True)
        fixation.draw()
        win.flip()
        core.wait(1.0)

win.close()
core.quit()
```

Comment: If you have a follow-up question it should be posted in a separate thread.